# javah not able to find android classes

Tags: android, native, classnotfoundexception

When calling javah on a .java file in my android project, javah was unable to find the android classes (specifically android.graphics.Bitmap).

here's the terminal output:

```
thomas@THOMASDESKLINUX:~$ javah -classpath .:/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/RenderScene/bin org.me.renderscene.Billboard
javadoc: error - In doclet class com.sun.tools.javah.MainDoclet,  method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.graphics.Bitmap not found
1 error
```

help appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to add {android-sdk-path}\platforms\android-8\android.jar also to the classpath